# SharePoint 2010 filter issues

Tags: sharepoint-2010, filtering

In SharePoint 2010, I want to automatically filter a library/database similar to the way a choice filter works, but different per user, which would be just like the current user filter.

Is there a way to combine these two filters or is there another filter that is able to automatically filter the information for the current user of the site?

If possible, I would prefer the filter to be invisible to all users (as in readers/contributors).

Comment: are you requiring a column level filter or an item level filter?

Comment: I require two item level filters that are automatically applied to multiple accounts in a different way, which depends on the rank of the group within the company and the country the group operates in.

If, for example, a General Manager from England wants to log in, I want his view to be filtered to meet his specifications, which are: England as country and GM as rank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I do understand it correctly, but if you're referring to having a view that would be base on a column with your name, you could go to library(for doc libraries)/list(for lists) and then click on create view, create a standard view and let it become your default view. On the filters portion, place in the column you would want to filter and place on the value [Me]. This would filter all items which only has the users name on that field. You could also place in more filters if necessary.

Comment: It's more like this: In our company, we have different user groups, each with its own permission level. Due to the confidentiality issue, we would like to have a set of filters that automatically apply to each user group based on the function the persons in that group entail and the country the user group operates in. I have so far been able to do this manually with the choice filter, but it resets every time I log in and it can be changed by every user. I was wondering whether it was possible to use a choice filter (or several) that is/are automatically applied to each user group differently.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out a way to realize it. It requires several choice filters, but that's just a minor downside. If you edit a choice filter and go to 'advanced filter options', you can type in the value of choice by which the database needs to be filtered in 'default value' and if you go to 'Advanced' you can select the target audience, therewith enabling the choice filter to only work on the required group(s) and/or person(s).

By putting all the different groups of one country in the same choice filter and all similar office ranks in the same choice filters, the amount of choice filters will be relatively low and I will be able to maintain an easily managable system.

Although I finally managed to fix it on my own, I'd like to thank all of you who tried to help me with my problem, you've encouraged me to keep trying (: